# Best way to display web content on my iPhone app (if possible without using UIWebView)

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uilabel

I want to build an iPhone app that should , among other things, display the some content of a website's detail pages. This content includes  a)a title b) an image c) a text passage (with multiple paragraphs.

I have done a brief research and found out that the easiest way to do this is by using uiwebview. The problem is that in that scenario I would have to be constantly in touch with the person responsible for the website in order to create a modified html/css version for the iPhone client.

As a result I was wondering if there is a feasible alternative. I can get the data I want in json format with HTML Requests. Maybe if I used a UIScrollView that contains a UILabel for the title, a UIImage for the image and another UILabel for the text passage? But the problem is how to set the UIscrollview content size since it dependent on the size of the text passage?

I am a iPhone dev noob and I am possibly missing something obvious here so I would be very greatful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are building an app ontop of somebody elses content. Provided this is legal, this other site should have a published api where you can start to write your app.  Get the json or xml, then populate them in a `UIViewController` using a `UIImageView` to display the image, `UITextView` for the text. The `UITextView` already has a built in scroller so you dont need a `UIScrollView`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer cneybear. The reason I didn't mention UITextView is because by using it, the image would be always visble and only the text would be scrollable whereas I would prefer a more "web-page-like" feel (i.e. with the whole content being scrollable). Of course, if there is no other way I will choose this path. The content is owned by the company I work for so nothing illegal here :-) . I am just trying to work with the given api (json data) without messing with the server,adding more files (html/css) etc

Comment: you can calculate the height of text - check out the NSString documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks again coneybear. This seems to work pretty well. I also found out that i can create the html as a string at runtime and then use it with UIWebview with loadHTMLString:baseURL:nil method. I was under the impression that one could only load an html file that rest on a server or an html file that is stored on the device.